# Log4Net not displaying an accurate Timestamp

Tags: log4net

I'm logging an Azure-based webapp using a Log4Net CSV appender with:

I'm seeing multiple entries with an identical timestamp - clearly not logging the actual instant of a given event on the server:

```
2018-03-19 21:59:52.000 OrderId: 191096  Starts to validate, multi: 
2018-03-19 21:59:52.000 OrderId: 191096  validation request:
2018-03-19 21:59:52.000 OrderId: 191096 passed validation. AuthKey:6128994
2018-03-19 21:59:52.000 OrderId: 191096 Single starts
2018-03-19 21:59:52.000 OrderId: 191096 submits: 
2018-03-19 21:59:52.000 SaveOrderChanges: 191096
2018-03-19 21:59:52.000 SaveOrderChanges: 191096
```

I had thought perhaps it take to do with when the logs are written out to file vs. when the entry is literally generated but unless I'm mis-reading the context, [this answer indicates otherwise](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8543626/118110).

Clearly I have something misconfigured. My CSV is built using code found at: http://element533.blogspot.com/2010/05/writing-to-csv-using-log4net.html

Full appender:

```
  <appender name="CsvFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
    <file value="D:/home/logfiles/log4netCSV.log" />
    <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
    <appendToFile value="true"/>
    <threshold value="INFO" />
    <layout type=" myWeb.CsvPatternLayout, myWeb">
      <header value="DateTime,Thread,Level,Logger,Message,Exception&#13;&#10;" />
      <conversionPattern value="%date%newfield[%thread]%newfield %-5level%newfield% %property{Ip} _+ %aspnet-request{ASP.NET_SessionId} _+ %logger %newfield%message%newfield%exception%endrow" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
```

Comment: Why couldn't multiple things happen in the same millisecond? Also, are you using any logging class that is an abstraction over log4net?  It sounds like there may be batching behavior coming from somewhere.

Comment: Strange I just tested that conversionPattern  `2018-04-06 19:02:53,893` Is the pattern I get with %date

Comment: @JamesFaix - note that the lines reference different operations against the same orderId so it's not possible that all occurred at the same time. Clearly batching - how do i turn it off?

Comment: @JamesFaix - to the 'abstraction over log4net' question: Aside from the adoption of the CSV appender noted in the link, I'm not (knowingly) doing anything to Log4Net - any thoughts on how troubleshoot where the batching is injecting itself?

Comment: @justSteve Normally I would try using a step-through debugger to see when your app is making calls to log4net methods.  I don't have any experience with Azure, and I've just started getting into cloud stuff with AWS very recently, so I'm not sure what's available for debugging there.  Maybe Azure is partially responsible?  If step-thru is not an option, can you create a similar subsystem in a local app and see if it behaves the same?

Answer (score 2):

It is very strange that your dates are showing 
`2018-03-19 21:59:52.000`

The default format is Iso8601 and separator between second and milisec is a comma:
https://github.com/apache/logging-log4net/blob/master/src/DateFormatter/Iso8601DateFormatter.cs#L26

I recommend you to use explicit dates:
`%date{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff}`
Also if you want a CSV file you need to separate the values with commas:

`<conversionPattern value="%date{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff},[%thread],%level,..." />`

#### Update:

I just tested this on Azure to see if it had anything to do, and it shows correctly:
http://swagger-net-test.azurewebsites.net/log4net.log
I have two log actions one right after the other and they do show different time stamps

```
DateTime,Thread,Level,Logger,Message
2018-04-08 13:19:48.658,[20],INFO,Swagger_Test.Controllers.LogController,Test1
2018-04-08 13:19:48.689,[20],ERROR,Swagger_Test.Controllers.LogController,Test2
```

Comment: Not sure why my date would be showing as is since i'm not (knowingly) over-riding anything (though I notice that the sample output in the linked article is showing the same way). The '%newfield' is playing the role of the comma.

Comment: @justSteve Try a few different combinations of the date format (like removing the year), make sure the logs reflect your changes, if not something is definitely over-riding your dates